# Consuming an image from Firebase Storage as soon as I upload it

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm making myself a React portfolio to show my other projects, and as the idea started to grow, I had to implement more features. It went from a front end project only to a full stack one. This is when I decided I wanted to make my portfolio a CMS where I can add as many projects as I wanted, as well as removing them, without touching the code.

Case is, I'm using a Node.JS backend and a Postgres database that I hit with my endpoints to store and retrieve data, but I also need images, and AFAIK, I can't store images there.

So, I chose to use Firebase, and I can effectively store my images there, and retrieve the link of the last one on the array Firebase returns with this listAll and getDownloadURL functions.

All of this works locally, meaning that if I just use some random online image path, I can use my 'addProject' function I have in my API folder, which connects to my backend successfully, and stores the url on the database, so when I call my projects, it has an image.

Problem is, when I submit the form, the fetchImageHandler function fails to set the state 'projectImage' to the url it got (it actually logs it to the console), so by missing this, the addProject function receives '' as the source argument, so no image is set to the project.

Here's my code:

first, the functions I use

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Project from '../../molecules/ProjectList/Project'
import cross from '../../../assets/images/x-icon.svg'
import { addProject } from '../../../../API'
import { storage } from '../../../../API/firebase'
import { ref, uploadBytes, listAll, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import { v4 } from 'uuid'

const AddProject = ({ editHandler, projects }) => {

    const [name, setName] = useState([])
    const [technologies, setTechnologies] = useState([])
    const [src, setSrc] = useState('')
    const [deploy, setDeploy] = useState('')
    const [git, setGit] = useState('')

    const [preview, setPreview] = useState('')

    //firebase implementation tests
    const [projectImage, setProjectImage] = useState('')
    const imageListRef = ref(storage, 'images/')

    const onChangeNameHandler = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangeTechnologiesHandler = (e) => {
        setTechnologies(e.target.value.split(","))
    }

    const onChangeSrcHandler = (e) => {
        setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
        setSrc(e.target.files[0])
        console.log(preview)
        console.log(src)
    }

    const onChangeDeployHandler = (e) => {
        setDeploy(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangeGitHandler = (e) => {
        setGit(e.target.value)
    }


    const fetchImageHandler = async () => {
        const imagesList = await listAll(imageListRef)
        const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imagesList.items[imagesList.items.length-1])
        console.log(imageUrl) // it actually shows the URL i need!
        setProjectImage(imageUrl) // but it does not set it here
    }

    const removeImageHandler = () => {
        setPreview('')
        setSrc('')
    }

    const uploadImage = async () => {
        if (src == null || src.length == 0) return
        const srcRef = ref(storage, `images/${src.name + v4()}`)
        await uploadBytes(srcRef, src)
        alert("image uploaded")
    }

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        await uploadImage()  
        await fetchImageHandler()
        console.log(projectImage)
        addProject(name, technologies, projectImage, deploy, git) //so here where I need to use it, it does not work
        editHandler()  
    }
```

my jsx looks like this:
[my return code, a form where each input strikes their own function, and a submit handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiLJ1.png). Sorry I uploaded an image instead of the code itself, the classNames are quite messy

I've been fighting with this one for two days now so thanks In advance if you manage to solve it!

I tried async await on the functions so it can take its time to set the projectImage state to the firebase image URL and also using promises. None of them worked.

Images are correctly uploaded to my firebase storage and the link I retreive is the correct one